# Magento load customer data not working

Tags: magento, load, observers

I have an issue in one of my observer's functions.
For some reason I can't load the customer information for further manipulation

```
$user = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$usertemp = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($user->getId());
```

I checked and $user->getId() actually carries the id; however when I try, for example:

```
$password = $usertemp->getPassword();
```

a null value is set instead of the user's password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - why do you load `customer` object, if you already have one from `$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()`? This operation is of excess here and will just increase resource and time consuming.

Second - for security measure Magento does not store user password in decrypted form. If you want to get user password, try next code:

```
$passwHash = $customer->getPasswordHash();
$password = Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($passwHash); // this will not work
```

**Update**: `Mage::helper('core')->decrypt` will not decrypt password hash, since it was hashed with md5 hash function, so there is a way to check if passwords are identical (`Mage::helper('core')->validateHash`), but you can't retrieve the original password.

**Update 2**: So question asker has some few interesting questions, which he provided in the comments, I will address those here:

1. Why hash for **123456** is `0f474c41fd20617eb8f1a0cb9b08f3aa:Uh` while it should have been `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` in md5. The answer is  - because `hash` method not only hashes incoming password, but also a randomly generated salt. Take a look at this method:

   ```
   public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
   {
       if (is_integer($salt)) {
           $salt = $this->_helper->getRandomString($salt);
       }
       return $salt === false ? $this->hash($password) : $this->hash($salt . $password) . ':' . $salt;
   }
   ```

   And these two methods in `Customer` model:

   ```
   public function setPassword($password)
   {
       $this->setData('password', $password);
       $this->setPasswordHash($this->hashPassword($password));
       return $this;
   }
   public function hashPassword($password, $salt = null)
   {
       return Mage::helper('core')->getHash($password, !is_null($salt) ? $salt : 2);
   }
   ```

   So since the `$salt` argument is integer (2), the actual salt is randomly generated string. That's why you have different output hash, than you would have if you simple `md5($passw)`.
2. > Also I was working directly with the getPassword() because it was working on user register

   That's a bit easier. During the `registering` process you have a `$_POST` data with raw password. With the help of `$customer->setPassword($passw)` you set it to `$customer` model. If you look at this function above, you'll see that both `password` and `password` hash attributes are set during this action. The only difference it: `password` isn't really an existing attribute, which means that it will not be stored at the DB, or anywhere else, and it will get lost as soon as `$customer` object is cleared from the memory.

**There is no way to get user password in Magento**. The only thing you can do, is compare given password with existing `password_hash` (as I mentioned before): `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::validateHash`

```
public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    switch (count($hashArr)) {
        case 1:
            return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
        case 2:
            return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
    }
    Mage::throwException('Invalid hash.');
}
```

Comment: the event's object does not contain (appart from password) the Social Security Number, and the phone, I would like to load a new object to obtain this info.

Comment: Also your solution with the password didn't work for me, when logging $password some random weird characters showed up

Comment: @EnforcerW that makes sense, please see my update - you actually can't get the original password..

Comment: The password is a one way hash, and by definition you will not be able to get the original password (without work reversing it)

Comment: and how about the other variables that I still can't manage to load?

Comment: BTW, tried the getPasswordHash() but the result is not the expected one. I mean, let's say the password is 123456 so the md5 has should be e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e; however the passwordHash() gives the following: 0f474c41fd20617eb8f1a0cb9b08f3aa:Uh

Comment: Also I was working directly with the getPassword() because it was working on user register

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @SlayerBirden; still I have some other questions. 1.- So there is no way to obtain the pure md5 hash (e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e)?. 2.-My original question also contemplated that getting the password was one of my problems but I also couldn't get other attributes like the Social Security Number and the Phone.

Comment: I've resolved the second question of my previous comment. I'm still stuck with the first one, if is not possible to obtain the unsalted md5 hash, is there a way to recreate the same hashing in let's say Objective C? (this is my other system integrated to Magento, so if I cannot have the normal md5 hash in Magento I would like to do the same md5 salted hash in the Objective C side so both passwords be equal)

Comment: I managed to implement the Magento-like password hashing in Objective C and the "decrypter"